# AngularJS/UI-Router: section of site needs nested views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an existing application made with angular js 1.4.9 and ui-router 0.2.18.

The index.html page lays out 3 ui-views, which the whole app shares:

- header
- site body
- footer

Each landing page of each existing section consists of a `ui-view`. with a route:

```
angular.module('pb.ds.hamburger').config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('hamburger', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/hamburger',
  templateUrl: 'modules/hamburger/templates/hamburger.html',
  controller: 'HamburgerController as burger'
})
```

which loads the root page:

```
  .state('hamburger.overview', {
  url: '/overview',
  templateUrl: 'modules/hamburger/templates/hamburger-overview.html',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Full-Time Hamburger Menu - Overview',
    access: 'public',
    bodyClass: ''
  }
```

Which displays the header and footer as defined in index.html and the hamburger content in the `site` view.

This new section requires me to load a DIFFERENT header and page structure, but load the view from the route in the main `ui-view` as before.

What's the proper way to do this?  My supervisor tells me to create a whole new index.html, but I have a feeling I can do this with views...

I hsve tried

```
angular.module('pb.ds.hamburger').config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('hamburger', {
  url: '/hamburger',
  templateUrl: 'modules/hamburger/templates/hamburger.html',
  views: {
    'newheader': 'modules/hamburger/templates/test1.html',
    'body': 'modules/hamburger/templates/test2.html'
  },
  controller: 'HamburgerController as burger'
})
```

where `hamburger.html is:

```
<div ui-view="newheader"></div>
<div ui-view="body"></div>
```

but instead of seeing this, I simply see the payout defined in index:  a page with the default header, empty content view, and the footer.

Comment: I dont know if I completely understood your question but it seems like now, you header + body depend on the url as opposed to just the body. If so, you can put both the header and body into the ui-view in the root, then use named views to populate them state by state.

Comment: For a variety of reasons, I'm not allowed to make major changes to the root application.  I have to just add my section to what's there...